# ANTLR v3 NoViableAltException not showing up

Tags: exception, antlr

consider following extract of my grammar:

```
definition
    :   '(' 'define' 
                   ( '(' variable def_formals ')' body ')'
                   | variable expression ')'
                   )    
    ;

def_formals
    :   variable* ('.' variable)?
    ;

body
    :   ((definition)=> definition)* expression+
    ;
```

variables are Identifiers, expressions are some expressions of scheme (like literals or lambda expressions). the full grammar can be found in some of my other questions.

so i was testing the whole thing and came up with an issue regarding the NoViableException.

so far, everything what should run fine runs fine. 
for example

```
(define x 5)
```

is recognized.

now i was testing what the parser should NOT recognize.

for example

```
(define x 5))
```

reports about the extra ")" at the end of the line.

but when i leave stuff out, for example

```
(define x)
```

or

```
(define)
```

the parser doesn't complain at all. when i check the interpreter, the NoViableAltException shows up correctly. but i can't figure out how to get this error to show up in an external programm (like a java test class)

i tried to make the parser break up on the first syntax error he sees like described in the book from Terrence Parr (page 252), but that didn't help either.
i also tried something like

```
    private List<String> errors = new LinkedList<String>();
    public void displayRecognitionError(String[] tokenNames,
                                       RecognitionException e) {
        String hdr = getErrorHeader(e);
        String msg = getErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
        errors.add(hdr + " " + msg);
    }
    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
```

but that method doesn't return anything when called.

so how do i get ANTLR to show me this errors when they are clearly being thrown internally?

edit:
this is the whole grammar:

```
grammar R5RS;

options {
  language = Java;
  output=AST;
}

@header{
    package r5rsgrammar;
    import r5rsgrammar.scope.*;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
}

@lexer::header{
    package r5rsgrammar;
    import r5rsgrammar.scope.*;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
}

@members{   

    // variables wich is used to distinguish between top level and inner definitions
    private boolean topLevel;


    // the toplevel scope of a file, whose parent is null
    private IScope scope;

    @Override
    public void emitErrorMessage(String message) {
        throw new RuntimeException(message);
    }
}

// PROGRAMS AND DEFINITIONS

parse
@init{
    this.topLevel = true;
    this.scope = new Scope();   
}
    :   command_or_definition* EOF
    ;

command_or_definition
    :   (syntax_definition)=>               syntax_definition
    |   (definition)=>                      definition
    |   ('('BEGIN command_or_definition)=>  
            '('BEGIN 
                {   this.topLevel = false;
                    this.scope = this.scope.push();
                }
                command_or_definition+
                {   this.scope = this.scope.pop();
                    this.topLevel = true;
                }')'
    |   command
    ;

command
  :  expression
  ;

definition
    :   '(' DEFINE ( '(' var=variable 
                        {   this.topLevel = false;
                            this.scope.bind($var.text);
                            this.scope = this.scope.push();
                        }
                            def_formals ')' body 
                        {   this.topLevel = true;
                            this.scope = this.scope.pop();
                        }')'
                   | var=variable 
                        {   this.topLevel = false;
                            this.scope.bind($var.text);
                            this.scope = this.scope.push();
                        }
                            expression 
                        {   this.topLevel = true;
                            this.scope = this.scope.pop();
                        }')'
                   )
    |   '(' BEGIN 
            {this.scope = this.scope.push();}
            definition* 
            {this.scope = this.scope.pop();}')'
    ;

def_formals
    :   vars+=variable* ('.' vars+=variable)?
        {for (int i = 0; i \less $vars.size(); i++){
            String name = ((CommonTree)$vars.get(i)).getText();
            this.scope.bind(name);
            }
        }
    ;


syntax_definition
    :   '(' DEFINE_SYNTAX var=variable 
                        {   this.scope.bind($var.text);
                            this.scope = this.scope.push();}
                            transformer_spec 
                            {this.scope = this.scope.pop();}')'
    ;

// EXPRESSIONS

expression 
    :   (variable)=>            var=variable 
                                {
                                    if(!this.scope.isBound($var.text))
                                    System.err.println($var.text + " not bound");
                                }
    |   (literal)=>             literal
    |   (lambda_expression)=>   lambda_expression
    |   (conditional)=>         conditional
    |   (assignment)=>          assignment
    |   (derived_expression)=>  derived_expression
    |   (procedure_call)=>      procedure_call 
    |   (macro_use)=>           macro_use
    |                           macro_block
    ;

keyword
    :   identifier
    ;

literal
    :   quotation
    |   self_evaluating
    ;

self_evaluating
    :   bool
    |   number
    |   CHARACTER
    |   STRING
    ;

quotation
    :   '\'' datum
    |   '(' QUOTE datum ')'
    ;

lambda_expression
    :   '(' LAMBDA  {this.scope = this.scope.push();}
                    formals body 
                    {this.scope = this.scope.pop();}')'
    ;

formals
    :   '(' (vars+=variable+ ('.' vars+=variable )?)? ')'
        {for (int i = 0; i \less $vars.size(); i++){
            String name = ((CommonTree)$vars.get(i)).getText();
            this.scope.bind(name);
            }
        }
    |   var=variable
        {this.scope.bind($var.text);}
    ;

body
    :   ((definition)=> definition)* sequence
    ;

sequence
    :   expression+
    ;


conditional
    :   '(' IF test consequent alternate? ')'
    ;

test
    :   expression
    ;
consequent
    :   expression
    ;
alternate
    :   expression
    ;

assignment
    :   '(' SET_BANG variable expression ')'
    ;


derived_expression
    :   quasiquotation
    |   '(' ( COND ( '(' ELSE sequence ')'
                   | cond_clause+ ('(' ELSE sequence ')')?
                   )
            | CASE expression ( case_clause+ ('(' ELSE sequence ')')? 
                              | '(' ELSE sequence ')'
                              )     
            | AND test* 
            | OR test* 
            | LET variable? '(' {this.scope = this.scope.push();}
                                binding_spec[false] ')' body
                                {this.scope = this.scope.pop();}
            | LET_STAR '(' {this.scope = this.scope.push();}
                            binding_spec[true] ')' body 
                            {this.scope = this.scope.pop();}
            | LETREC '(' {this.scope = this.scope.push();}
                            binding_spec[true] ')' body 
                            {this.scope = this.scope.pop();}
            | BEGIN sequence 
            | DO '(' iteration_spec* ')' '(' test do_result? ')' command* 
            | DELAY expression 
            )
        ')'

    ;

cond_clause
    :   '(' test (sequence | FOLLOWS recipient)? ')'
    ;

recipient
    :   expression
    ;

case_clause
    :   '(' '(' datum* ')' sequence ')'
    ;

binding_spec[boolean sequential]
    :   {sequential}? // let* or letrec: bind the var immediatly
        ('(' var=variable 
        {this.scope.bind($var.text);} 
            expression ')')*

    |   {!sequential}?  // normal let: bind all vars at the end
        ('(' vars+=variable expression ')')*
        {for (int i = 0; i \less $vars.size(); i++){
            String name = ((CommonTree)$vars.get(i)).getText();
            this.scope.bind(name);
            }
        }
    ;

iteration_spec
    :   '(' variable init step ')'
    ;

init
    :   expression
    ;

step
    :   expression
    ;

do_result
    :   sequence
    ;

procedure_call
    :   '(' operator operand* ')'
    ;

operator
    :   expression
    ;

operand
    :   expression
    ;

macro_use
    :   '(' keyword datum* ')'
    ;

macro_block
    :   '(' (LET_SYNTAX | LETREC_SYNTAX) '(' syntax_spec*')' body ')'
    ;

syntax_spec
    :   '(' keyword transformer_spec')'
    ;


// TRANSFORMERS

transformer_spec
    :   '(' SYNTAX_RULES '(' identifier* ')' syntax_rule* ')'
    ;

syntax_rule
    :   '(' pattern template ')'
    ;

pattern
    :   pattern_identifier
    |   '(' (pattern+ ('.' pattern)?)? ')'
    |   '#(' (pattern+ ELLIPSIS?)? ')'
    |   pattern_datum
    ;

pattern_datum
    :   bool
    |   number
    |   CHARACTER
    |   STRING
    ;

template
    :   pattern_identifier
    |   '(' (template_element+ ('.' template)?)? ')'
    |   '#('template_element* ')'
    |   template_datum
    ;

template_element
    :   template ELLIPSIS?
    ;

template_datum
    :   pattern_datum
    ;

pattern_identifier
    :   syntactic_keyword
    |   VARIABLE
    ;

// external representations
// a Datum is what the _read_ procedure successfully parses. 
// Note that any string that parses as an expression will also parse as a datum.
datum 
    : simple_datum 
    | compound_datum
    ;

simple_datum 
    :   bool
    |   number
    |   CHARACTER
    |   STRING
    |   identifier
    ;

compound_datum 
    : list 
    | vector
    ;

list 
    :   '(' (datum+ ( '.' datum)?)? ')'
    |   abbreviation
    ;

abbreviation
    :   abbrev_prefix datum
    ;

abbrev_prefix
    :   ('\''   | '`' | ',' | ',@')
    ;

vector 
    : '#(' datum* ')'
    ; 

// QUASIQUOTATIONS
// CONTEXT-SENSITIVE

quasiquotation
  :  quasiquotation_D[1]
  ;

quasiquotation_D[int d]
  :  '`' qq_template[d]
  |  '(' QUASIQUOTE qq_template[d] ')'
  ;

qq_template[int d]
  :  (expression)=>  expression
  |  ('(' UNQUOTE)=> unquotation[d]
  |                  simple_datum
  |                  vectorQQ_template[d]
  |                  listQQ_template[d]
  ;

vectorQQ_template[int d]
  :  '#(' qq_template_or_slice[d]* ')'
  ;

listQQ_template[int d]
  :                     '\'' qq_template[d]
  |  ('(' QUASIQUOTE)=> quasiquotation_D[d+1]
  |                     '(' (qq_template_or_slice[d]+ ('.' qq_template[d])?)? ')'
  ;

unquotation[int d]
  :  ',' qq_template[d-1]
  |  '(' UNQUOTE qq_template[d-1] ')'
  ;

qq_template_or_slice[int d]
  :  ('(' UNQUOTE_SPLICING)=> splicing_unquotation[d]
  |                           qq_template[d]
  ;

splicing_unquotation[int d]
  :  ',@' qq_template[d-1]
  |  '(' UNQUOTE_SPLICING qq_template[d-1] ')'
  ;



// values

bool: TRUE | FALSE;
number: NUM_2 | NUM_8 | NUM_10 | NUM_16;
identifier: syntactic_keyword | variable;
variable : VARIABLE | ELLIPSIS;

// KEYWORDS

syntactic_keyword 
    : expression_keyword 
    | ELSE  
    | FOLLOWS 
    | DEFINE 
    | UNQUOTE 
    | UNQUOTE_SPLICING;
expression_keyword 
    : QUOTE 
    | LAMBDA 
    | IF 
    | SET_BANG 
    | BEGIN 
    | COND 
    | AND 
    | OR 
    | CASE 
    | LET 
    | LET_STAR 
    | LETREC 
    | DO 
    | DELAY 
    | QUASIQUOTE;

// syntactic keywords
ELSE : 'else';
FOLLOWS : '=>';
DEFINE : 'define';
UNQUOTE : 'unquote';
UNQUOTE_SPLICING : 'unquote-splicing';

// expression keywords
QUOTE : 'QUOTE';
LAMBDA : 'lambda';
IF : 'if';
SET_BANG : 'set!';
BEGIN : 'begin';
COND : 'cond';
AND : 'and';
OR : 'or';
CASE : 'case';
LET : 'let';
LET_STAR : 'let*';
LETREC : 'letrec';
DO : 'do';
DELAY : 'delay';
QUASIQUOTE : 'quasiquote';

// macro keywords
LETREC_SYNTAX : 'letrec-syntax';
LET_SYNTAX : 'let-syntax';
SYNTAX_RULES : 'syntax_rules';
DEFINE_SYNTAX : 'define-syntax';

ELLIPSIS : '...';

//RESERVED_CHAR : '{'| '}' | '[' | ']' | '|';

STRING : '"' STRING_ELEMENT* '"';

TRUE : '#' ('T' | 't');
FALSE : '#' ('f' | 'F');

CHARACTER : '#\\' (~(' ' | '\n') | CHARACTER_NAME);

VARIABLE : INITIAL SUBSEQUENT* | PECULIAR_IDENTIFIER;

// space and comments are ignored
SPACE : (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;}; 
COMMENT : ';' ~('\r' | '\n')* {$channel = HIDDEN;};


fragment INITIAL : LETTER | SPECIAL_INITIAL;
fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment SPECIAL_INITIAL : '!' | '$' | '%' | '&' | '*' | '/' | ':' | '\less' | '=' | '>' | '?' | '^' | '_' | '~';
fragment SUBSEQUENT : INITIAL | DIGIT | SPECIAL_SUBSEQUENT;
fragment SPECIAL_SUBSEQUENT : '+' | '-' | '.' | '@';
fragment PECULIAR_IDENTIFIER : '+' | '-';
fragment STRING_ELEMENT : ~('"' | '\\') | '\\' ('"' | '\\');
fragment CHARACTER_NAME : 'space' | 'newline';



// NUMBERS

fragment SUFFIX : EXPONENT_MARKER SIGN? DIGIT+; 
fragment EXPONENT_MARKER : 'e' | 'E' | 's' | 'S' | 'f' | 'F' | 'd' | 'D' | 'l' |'L';
fragment SIGN : '+' |  '-';
fragment EXACTNESS : '#' ('i' | 'I' | 'e' | 'E');
fragment IMAGINARY : 'i' | 'I';
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';

// BINARY NUMBERS

NUM_2 : PREFIX_2 COMPLEX_2;

fragment COMPLEX_2
  :  REAL_2 ('@' REAL_2)?
  |  REAL_2? ('+' | '-') UREAL_2? IMAGINARY
  ;         
fragment REAL_2 : SIGN? UREAL_2;
fragment UREAL_2 : UINTEGER_2 ('/' UINTEGER_2)?;    
fragment UINTEGER_2 : DIGIT_2+ '#'*;

fragment PREFIX_2 
    : RADIX_2  EXACTNESS? // #d #i
    | EXACTNESS RADIX_2 // #i #d
    ; 

fragment RADIX_2 : '#' ('b' | 'B'); 
fragment DIGIT_2 : '0' | '1';

// OCTAL NUMBERS

NUM_8 : PREFIX_8 COMPLEX_8;

fragment COMPLEX_8
  :  REAL_8 ('@' REAL_8)?
  |  REAL_8? ('+' | '-') UREAL_8? IMAGINARY
  ;

fragment REAL_8 : SIGN? UREAL_8;

fragment UREAL_8 
    : UINTEGER_8 ('/' UINTEGER_8)?;

fragment UINTEGER_8 : DIGIT_8+ '#'*;

fragment PREFIX_8 
    : RADIX_8  EXACTNESS? // #d #i
    | EXACTNESS RADIX_8; // #i #d

fragment RADIX_8 : '#' ('o' | 'O'); 
fragment DIGIT_8 : '0' .. '7';

// DECIMAl NUMBERS

NUM_10 : PREFIX_10? COMPLEX_10;

fragment COMPLEX_10
  :  REAL_10 ('@' REAL_10)?
  |  REAL_10? ('+' | '-') UREAL_10? IMAGINARY
  ;

fragment REAL_10 : SIGN? UREAL_10;
fragment UREAL_10 : UINTEGER_10 ('/' UINTEGER_10)? | DECIMAL_10;    
fragment UINTEGER_10 : DIGIT+ '#'*; 

fragment DECIMAL_10 
    : UINTEGER_10 SUFFIX
    | '.' DIGIT+ '#'* SUFFIX?
    | DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT* '#'* SUFFIX?
    | DIGIT+ '#'+ '.' '#'* SUFFIX?;

fragment PREFIX_10 
    : RADIX_10  EXACTNESS? // #d #i
    | EXACTNESS RADIX_10; // #i #d

fragment RADIX_10 : '#' ('d' | 'D'); 

// HEXADECIMAL NUMBERS

NUM_16 : PREFIX_16 COMPLEX_16;

fragment COMPLEX_16
  :  REAL_16 ('@' REAL_16)?
  |  REAL_16? ('+' | '-') UREAL_16? IMAGINARY
  ;

fragment REAL_16 : SIGN? UREAL_16;

fragment UREAL_16 
    : UINTEGER_16 ('/' UINTEGER_16)?;

fragment UINTEGER_16 : DIGIT_16+ '#'*;

fragment PREFIX_16 
    : RADIX_16  EXACTNESS? // #d #i
    | EXACTNESS RADIX_16; // #i #d

fragment RADIX_16 : '#' ('x' | 'X'); 
fragment DIGIT_16 : DIGIT | 'a'.. 'f' | 'A' .. 'F';
```

(i had to replace "<" with "\less" in order to make the formatation work)

**EDIT**
the solution to this problem was far simpler: (define x) is (surprisingly valid in r5rs (see last comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to improve error reporting. A quick fix would be to override `emitErrorMessage(String message)` in the parser class and simply throw an exception with the provided message:

```java
grammar T;

@members {
  @Override
  public void emitErrorMessage(String message) {
    throw new RuntimeException(message);
  }
}

definition
  :  '(' 'define' ( '(' variable def_formals ')' body ')'
                  | variable expression ')'
                  )    
  ;

def_formals
  :  variable* ('.' variable)?
  ;

body
  :   ((definition)=> definition)* expression+
  ;

expression
  :  INT
  ;

variable
  :  ID
  ;

ID    : 'a'..'z'+;
INT   : '0'..'9';
SPACE : ' ' {skip();};
```

which you can test with the class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = {
        "(define x 5)",
        "(define x 5))",
        "(define x)",
        "(define)"
    };
    for(String input : tests) {
      TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(input));
      TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
      System.out.println("\nParsing : " + input);
      try {
        parser.definition();
      } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("  exception -> " + e.getMessage());  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After running the class above, you will see the following:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main

Parsing : (define x 5)

Parsing : (define x 5))

Parsing : (define x)
  exception -> line 1:9 missing INT at ')'

Parsing : (define)
  exception -> line 1:7 no viable alternative at input ')'
```

As you can see, the input `(define x 5))` produces no exception! That is because the lexer has no problems with it (they're all valid tokens) and the parser is simply instructed to consume the `definition` rule:

```java
definition
  :  '(' 'define' ( '(' variable def_formals ')' body ')'
                  | variable expression ')'
                  )    
  ;
```

which it does. If you wanted an error because of the dangling `')'`, then you'd have the add the `EOF` token at the end of the rule:

```java
definition
  :  '(' 'define' ( '(' variable def_formals ')' body ')'
                  | variable expression ')'
                  )
                  EOF
  ;
```

Comment: i reproduced this with your example, but when i try to assign this to my grammar, again, nothing happens. i posted the whole grammar as it is now above.

Comment: i tried to track it down, and i added some printouts when he entered the rule and when he left the rule. what i get is: he enteres the rule but he doesn't leave it. could there be some kind of loop where he cant get out?

Comment: ok i got it; in my grammar, (define x) is not wrong because he thinks it's a macro (rule macro_use), even (define) would match that rule. thanks anyways!

Comment: @Sebastian, I hadn't the time to look into your entire grammar. But your problem is solved I see at your last comment?

Comment: correct, but your answer was helpful anyways, because now i understand the error reporting mechanism in antlr a bit better.